# Chave estrangeira no MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Tenho a coleção ***users*** e a coleção ***compras***

A relação é 1 utilizador para N compras em que cada compra é um documento.

O que eu pretendia era, ao fazer um findOne na tabela users, automaticamente incluiria as compras, o resultado seria algo do gênero:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5430..."),
    "nome" : "Filipe",
    "email" : "email@dominio.com",
    "compras" : {
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5465..."),
            "data" : "23/05/2014",
            "valor" : "15.50"
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("895..."),
            "data" : "18/09/2014",
            "valor" : "78.25"
        },
    }
}
```

Como faço isso no MongoDB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Este trecho da resposta vale até antes da versão 3.2. Para versão 3.2 em diante, veja o restante da resposta.

Usando apenas o `findOne()` ou outros métodos de `find`, [não é possível porque o MongoDB não suporta joins, segundo a documentação oficial](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/database-references/).

O que você pode fazer é utilizar um framework da sua linguagem de programação da escolha pra resolver as referências pra você.

---

> Este trecho da resposta para a versão 3.2 em diante. Agradecimentos ao @PauloLuvisoto pela [complementação da resposta](http://pastebin.com/ahJ60rCx).

A partir da versão 3.2 do MongoDB há o operador [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/), capaz de fazer um *join* entre duas coleções.

No exemplo abaixo temos uma coleção chamada 'produtos', com os campos `_id`, `descricao` e `valor`. Temos também outra coleção chamada 'pedidos' com os campos `_id`, `nome_cliente`, `cidade` e `id_produto`. Este campo `id_produto` da coleção 'pedidos' será ligado ao campo `_id` da coleção 'produtos'.

Executaremos a agragação da seguinte forma:

```
db.pedidos.aggregate([
{
    $lookup:
    {
        from: "produtos",
        localField: "id_produto",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "desc_produto"
    }
}])
```

Obteremos um resultado como esse:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5685c8c74ad088fc05dcebe7"), "usuario" : "Carlos", "id_produto" : 1, "cidade" :
"Franca", "desc_produto" : [ { "_id" : 1, "titulo" : "Camisa", "valor" : 1500.3 } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5685c8d94ad088fc05dcebe8"), "usuario" : "Paulo H", "id_produto" : 2, "cidade" :
"Batatais", "desc_produto" : [ { "_id" : 2, "titulo" : "Saia", "valor" : 236.47 } ] }
```

Pode-se usar o `$lookup` para fazer *join* entre mais de duas tabelas. Exemplo:

```
db.pedidos.aggregate([
{
    $lookup:
    {
        from: "produtos",
        localField: "id_produto",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "desc_produto"
    }
},
{
    $lookup:
    {
        from: "clientes",
        localField: "id_cliente",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "desc_cliente"
    }
}])
```

A amarração pode ser feita através de qualquer campo, e não somente através dos campos `_id` como mostrado nos exemplos.

Comment: A nível de performance, ganha-se ao utilizar referências?

Comment: Pelo contrário. Performance só usando subdocumentos.

Comment: Mas como o documento é limitado a 16MB, é arriscado utilizar subdocumentos, certo? No exemplo acima não, chegar aos 16MB seria muita informação, mas creio que existem casos assim e neste caso seria necessário utilizar referência, certo?

Comment: Se compras cresce indefinidamente, sim.

Comment: A partir da versão 3.2 do mongodb, este tem um novo operador chamado $lookup, que é justamente pra fazer união de dados de coleções diferentes através de um campo em comum. Vale a pena dar uma olhada.

Comment: @PauloLuvisoto Poderia por favor me mandar o link com algum exemplo?

Comment: Cigano Morrison, está ai: http://pastebin.com/ahJ60rCx